# QGraphicsRectItem::pos() function returns something that is not expected?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have this simple piece of code in a class constructor which is inherited from `QGraphicsScene` :

```
setSceneRect(0,0,800,800);
addRect(sceneRect());
QGraphicsRectItem*r1 = addRect(200, 0, 5, 5);
qDebug()<<r1->pos();
```

Here I add a rect at pos(200,0) but `qDebug()` prints `QPointF(0, 0)`! I'm totally confused.
Even `scenePos` returns (0,0)! Is it true?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rect is at position (200, 0) inside the item's coordinate system, but the item itself is at (0,0) in its parent's coordinate system.

The [QGraphicsScene::addRect() documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html#addRect) explains this:

> Note that the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is initialized to (0, 0). For example, if a QRect(50, 50, 100, 100) is added, its top-left corner will be at (50, 50) relative to the origin in the items coordinate system.

Alternatively, you can add a rectangle at 0, 0, 5, 5) and move the item afterwards, to get the result you expected:

```
QGraphicsRectItem* r1 = addRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
r1->setPos(200, 0);
```